# Run SSMS 2012 as administrator Application can not start error

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

When i tried to run SSMS 2012 as administrator it gives the error "application can not start". I am using windows 8 64 bit and sql server 2012.

Actually yesterday i tried to install ssms 2005 side by side installation but i stopped the installation in the middle as it needed a feature to complete installation so i stopped it. Now i want to access SSMS 2012 as administrator as i have to access integration server which prompt me to access it as administrator which lead me to run SSMS 2012 as administrator.

Any help to resolve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Please reinstill the SSMS 2012 clien tool. or look at the env variable.

Comment: I uninstalled the sql server 2012 as well as SSMS 2012 but still getting the same error with new installed setup. It run fine with default run but error occur when i run SSMS 2012 as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to corrupt registries or some bad uninstall that removed files it shouldn't have. It's existed for years over multiple versions of VS and its shell. SSMS is dependent on the VS framework so it's among the potential victims, also spanning multiple versions.

This blog discusses some of the details of the problem and the comments section has some great feedback and possible solutions. The link should bring you directly to Oyvind Gellein's post whose solution worked for many. You can browse the rest of the page if you want to learn more.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/29/how-to-fix-the-application-cannot-start-error.aspx#10061076

You can also check out this other page for another potential solution
https://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/visual-studio-2012-4-run-as-administrator-the-application-cannot-start-error/

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is resolved by uninstalling all the SQl server components and VS frameworks. Then again reinstalled the sql server with SSMS.